# error in coverting a clob data to varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to convert a clob datatype to varchar2 datatype using the dbms_lob command, but im getting error as shown below

### ERROR:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

## table structure:

desc test_default_settings

```
Name          Null Type          
------------- ---- ------------- 
DEFAULT_KEY        VARCHAR2(100) 
DEFAULT_VALUE      CLOB
```

### Table Content:

```
Default_key                     Default_Value
======================        ==================
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_NAME             Invitation Email Template
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FROM             admin@xxx.com
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_SUBJECT          Welcome to test company!!!
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_EXP_DAYS         2
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MSG               <html><p>Dear  {First_Name}, {Last_Name}<span id="selectionBoundary_1496237162220_4685507087412435" class="rangySelectionBoundary">&#65279;</span></p><p>...
                                  ..................</html>
```

Since the value of the EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MSG is too long to display, for reference I have marked as "...."

query used :

```
SELECT e.default_key,
  TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(e.default_value,5000, 1)) AS DEFAULT_VALUE
FROM test_default_settings e;
```

Note:

I can extact all the  contents of data , except for **EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MSG** data

eg:

```
SELECT e.default_key,
  TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(e.default_value,5000, 1)) AS DEFAULT_VALUE
FROM test_default_settings e where default_key= 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_NAME';



  DEFAULT_KEY     DEFAULT_VALUE
--------------   ----------------
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_NAME Invitation Email Template
```

but when i do the same to extract the html content, im getting error

```
SELECT e.default_key,
  TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(e.default_value,5000, 1)) AS DEFAULT_VALUE
FROM test_default_settings e where default_key= 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MSG';
```

output:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

when i tried to increase the value of dbms_lob parameter to 80000, im getting the value as null.

Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR and SUBSTR work different. `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(amount,offset)` , `SUBSTR(offset,amount)`.

Example

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR('1234567890',5,1),substr('1234567890',5,1), 
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR('1234567890',1,5) 
from dw_mailing;
```

In your query `dbms_lob.SUBSTR` for long CLOB is extracting 5000 bytes and try to convert this byte to varchar2. But varchar2 max size in sql is 4000.

Comment: got it. so by default, no matter what the length of a clob, while converting to varchar i need to put the offset as 4000 !!!!?

Comment: max size of varchar2 is 4000 , so if you want to take first 4000 bytes from clob you have to do dbms_lob.substr(clob,4000,1) .